# Independent light switches are now dependent

Tags: switch, light

I did a replacement of two light switches that are next to one another. One switch controls a small outdoor sconce by our back door. The other switch controls the flood lights that illuminate the backyard.

Prior to my intervention, the switches worked independent from one another - though there is a wire that connects the two switches. I could turn either of them on or off without the other one needing to be one or off. But, after I did my thing, the sconce will not turn on unless the flood lights are also on.

Clearly, I've done something wrong. I'd prefer to get it back to the way it was. I'm thinking I must've botched the connecting wire placement, but have tried multiple different wire placement combinations with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you note how the connections were originally?

Comment: You probably connected the "wire that connects the two switches" to the switched side of one switch, rather than the hot side. Please be careful, experimentation is not allowed here, as the 3 wise men here have repeatedly said. With the power off, pull out the switches and shoot us some pictures if you haven't figured it out.

Comment: the wire bridge between the switches brings `hot` to the sconce switch ... you did not connect the wire bridge to the hot wire that comes into the switch box